# updating code from 5.0 to 9.0

Tags: packages, version-9, compatibility, broken-code, version-5

I am updating a code from a 5.0 version to a 9.0 version. I am speaking about "Advanced visual quantum mechanics".

There is a package with this code:

---

`

```
VQMmsgon  = Head[General::"spell"]  =!= $Off;
    VQMmsgon1 = Head[General::"spell1"] =!= $Off;

Off[General::spell1, General::spell];


(*-----------------------------------*)
BeginPackage["VQM`ArgColorPlot`"];
(*-----------------------------------*)
    ClearAll[QArgColorPlot,QListArgColorPlot];

(*-----------------------------------*)
Begin["`Private`"];
(*-----------------------------------*)
   If[!ValueQ[$UseListLinePlot],
        $UseListLinePlot=True;
];

Options[QArgColorPlot] := Sort @ {JoinOptions[
        {
        PlotStyle -> None
        },
        Options[ If[$UseListLinePlot, ListLinePlot, Plot] ],
        {
        Opacity -> 1,         
        Compiled->True, 
        QSaturation->1, QBrightness->1, QBottomLine->0, QShiftPlot->0, QPlotDown->False, 
        QSquared->False
        } ] };

Options[QListArgColorPlot] =  Sort @  Join[Options[QArgColorPlot],{QHorizontalRange->All}];

SetAttributes[QArgColorPlot,HoldAll];

QArgColorPlot[func_,{x_Symbol,xmin_,xmax_},opts___?OptionQ] :=
    Module[{comp,plot1,opts1,xvars,yvals},
        comp = Compiled/.Join[{opts}, Options[QArgColorPlot]];
        If[comp === True,
          abf = Compile[{x},Abs[func],{{func,_Complex}}];
          fnc = Compile[{x},func,{{func,_Complex}}], (*else*)
          abf = Abs[func];
          fnc = Function[{x},func];
        ];
        opts1   = FilterRules[{opts},Options@Plot];
        plot1   = Plot @@ { abf, {x,xmin,xmax}, 
                            {opts1} /. ( PlotStyle -> _ ) :> Sequence[]};
        xvars   = First /@ Level[plot1[[1]], {5}];
        yvals   = fnc /@ xvars; 

      QListArgColorPlot[{xvars,yvals}//Transpose, opts]
    ]/;NumericQ[xmin] && NumericQ[xmax]
EndPackage[]
```

### `

Comment: Please use the Code Sample button in the toolbar (the one with the `{}` icon) on your code so that it is formatted properly.

Comment: There is no `End[]` nor `EndPackage[]`, I presume they follow the current code immediately, correct?

Comment: yes there is EndPackage. The new error code is $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>

Comment: You just messed up the styling in its entirety with your update. Please go back and fix it. Lead every line of code with four spaces.

Answer (score 4):

I'd make several structural changes. First, instead of

```
Options[QArgColorPlot] := Sort @ {JoinOptions[ ... ]}
```

I'd use

```
Options[QArgColorPlot] = Sort @ Flatten @ { ... };
```

since rules are not flattened. Also, I changed it to `Set` (`=`), not `SetDelayed` (`:=`) as the options list is not likely to change during execution, so why bother recalculating it every time you use it.  Second, I'd use the new options constructs, `OptionsPattern` and `OptionValue` as they provide automatic messages if an option is unknown, and they eliminate constructs like

```
comp = Compiled/.Join[{opts}, Options[QArgColorPlot]];
```

which can be source of errors.  So, the signature of `QArgColorPlot` becomes

```
QArgColorPlot[func_,{x_Symbol,xmin_,xmax_},opts:OptionsPattern[]]
```

and the line to access the `Compiled` option then becomes

```
comp = OptionValue[Compiled];
```

Note, this automatically pulls in the pre-set values for the options. Third, `Plot` doesn't process `CompiledFunction` directly, but it can be made to work if an argument is passed to it. This requires to changes: first, the uncompiled code has to be treated consistently, so `abf` becomes

```
abf = Function[{x}, Abs[func]];
```

and, second, the call to `Plot` becomes

```
plot1 = Quiet[Plot@@{abf[x], {x,xmin,xmax}, opts1}, CompiledFunction::cfsa];
```

I had to add `Quiet` to get around a `Message`.  Lastly, in processing the options for `Plot`, I moved the `ReplaceAll` up one line

```
opts1 = FilterRules[{opts},Options@Plot] /. ( PlotStyle -> _ ) :> Sequence[];
```

Of course, that could be used directly in the call to `Plot`.

However, I was not able to reproduce the messages you saw. By any chance, are you resetting `Plot`?

---

As there is some question on what is or is not working, here is the full code with my changes:

```
BeginPackage["VQM`ArgColorPlot`"];
(*-----------------------------------*)
ClearAll[QArgColorPlot,QListArgColorPlot];

(*-----------------------------------*)
Begin["`Private`"];
(*-----------------------------------*)
   If[!ValueQ[$UseListLinePlot],
        $UseListLinePlot=True;
];

Options[QArgColorPlot] := Sort @ Flatten @{
    {
        PlotStyle -> None
    },
    Options[ If[$UseListLinePlot, ListLinePlot, Plot] ],
    {
        Opacity -> 1,         
        Compiled->True, 
        QSaturation->1, QBrightness->1, QBottomLine->0, 
        QShiftPlot->0, QPlotDown->False, 
        QSquared->False
    }
};

Options[QListArgColorPlot] = Sort@Join[Options[QArgColorPlot],{QHorizontalRange->All}];

SetAttributes[QArgColorPlot,HoldAll];

QArgColorPlot[func_,{x_Symbol,xmin_,xmax_},opts:OptionsPattern[]] :=
    Module[{comp,plot1,opts1,xvars,yvals},
        comp = OptionValue[Compiled];
        If[comp === True,
          abf = Compile[{x},Abs[func],{{func,_Complex}}];
          fnc = Compile[{x},func,{{func,_Complex}}], (*else*)
          abf = Function[{x}, Abs[func]];
          fnc = Function[{x},func];
        ];
        opts1   = FilterRules[{opts},Options@Plot]/. ( PlotStyle -> _ ) :> Sequence[];
        plot1   = Quiet[Plot @@ { abf[x], {x,xmin,xmax}, {opts1} }, 
                    CompiledFunction::cfsa];
        xvars   = First /@ Level[plot1[[1]], {5}];
        yvals   = fnc /@ xvars; 

      QListArgColorPlot[{xvars,yvals}//Transpose, opts]
    ]/;NumericQ[xmin] && NumericQ[xmax]
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

Then, using the now deleted example,

```
QArgColorPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True]
```

I get

```
(* 
QListArgColorPlot[{{2.04082*10^-8, 2.04082*10^-8}, ..., {1., 1.}}, 
 Frame -> True] 
*)
```

where the `...` are elided pairs of points. Obviously, `QListArgColorPlot` is not defined, yet, but running

```
ListLinePlot @@ QArgColorPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True]
```

I get

[image]

Comment: I still have problems when I call this function.
FilterRules::rep: ListLinePlot is not a valid replacement rule. >>

ListLinePlot::nonopt: Options expected (instead of FilterRules[ListLinePlot,Axes->True]) beyond position 3 in ListLinePlot[{{2.04082*10^-8,2.04082*10^-8},{0.000306718,0.000306718},{0.000613415,0.000613415},<<45>>,{0.857186,0.857186},{0.876771,0.876771},<<27>>},<<4>>,FilterRules[ListLinePlot,Axes->True]]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules. >>

FilterRules::rep: Graphics is not a valid replacement rule. >>

Show::gcomb: Could not combine the graphics objects in

Comment: Two things: do you run `Clear[QListArgColorPlot, QArgColorPlot]` anywhere? If not, please do so prior to running the code. Second, have you run the revised code in isolation from the rest of your package? Do you get the same errors?

Comment: I changed the code and you can read now the new version. But it is still not working

Comment: But, I still don't know if the code I gave you works in isolation from the rest of the package. Could you test that, please? As it works for me.

Comment: It is isolated. In the package now there is only your code

Comment: This is the new error line $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>

Comment: I'll look at it in a little bit. In the meantime, try restarting your kernel, and see if it helps.

Comment: Add the line `ClearAll[QArgColorPlot,QListArgColorPlot];` between `BeginPackage` and ``Begin[`Private`];`, instead of what is there. Then the change to `Options[QArgColorPlot]` and `abf` should make it work. There may be an extra `]` within the definition of `Options[QArgColorPlot]`, so make sure that is removed. Of course, there's a `CompiledFunction` message, but that can be covered by `Quiet`.

Comment: I fixed the code again but it is still not working.

Comment: In a new session, copy and paste the full version, which I just posted. Let me know what happens.

Comment: at the end I get the same result but when I call the package with << VQM`ArgColorPlot` then I get Get::bebal: Unterminated uses of BeginPackage or Begin in <<VQM`ArgColorPlot`. >>.

Comment: Added `End[]`. Did you run it in a clean kernel?

Comment: There is still a flag when a start the package, also after a kernel reset:
Get::bebal: Unterminated uses of BeginPackage or Begin in <<VQM`ArgColorPlot`. >>.
It finally works but in a different way from the original 5.0 version because :QArgColorPlot::usage = "QArgColorPlot[f[x],{x,x0,x1},opts] is used
like the usual Plot command. It gives a two-dimensional plot
of a complex-valued function f of a single real variable x
in the range {x0,x1}.

Comment: To get rid of that message, you need to add `End[]` to close the private section. Also, I don't know how you get the 2D plot. It wasn't present in your original code.